# Why the form submit button is reacting only in double-click?

Tags: php, forms, function, authentication, credentials

so I have a simple login page like this:

```
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Verification</legend>
   <form method="post" action="authentication.php">


<?php if($_GET['error']==1){
      echo "<p style=\"float: left; \" class=\"criticMsg\">Username or password are wrong</p>";  
    }
    ?>


 <br /><br /> <br /><br />
 <label style="float: left; margin-top: 15px;" for="username">User</label><input    type="text" name="username"></input><br />
 <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password"></input>  <br />
  <input type="submit" class="globalBtn" value="Enter"></input>
  </form>

    </fieldset>
```

then the authenticate.php file is like this:

```
 include ('functions.php');

if(valid_details($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
header("Location: ../../storage_update.php?message=1");
}else{
header("Location: login.php?error=1");
}
```

finally the functions.php looks like this

```
include("../connection.php");


$sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users";
$back = "There is an error. <a href=\"login.php\">Back</a>";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($back);

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

//validates user input

function valid_details($username, $password){
if(isset($username) && $username == $row->user){
   if(isset($password) && $password == $row->pass){
   return true;}
   }


  };
 }
```

When I type the correct username and password provided in the database I get the error=1 variable in the url, which is not what I expect on correct credentials. However if I fastly double click the submit button it gets me on the expected page returning message=1 in the url, so that it means the function valid_credentials is works ok, but why does the button react like that? **EDIT** In the page storage_update.php (the landing page) I have implemented fancybox jquery plugin.

Comment: his sounds like a client side error where the first click isnt properly sending the information. can you post the whole form. the form tags are missing. If you have javascript code its likely thats the problem. Post this also if there is any

Comment: Just added the cut out piece of code. Yes I'm using js, jquery to be precise, but only in the last landing page, the form sends the input to another page, which redirects the user to the final page upon input verification by the function validate_details().

Comment: You can get weirdness by using the ../ in a location header. A proper location header should be the fully qualified URL (including the http and the hostname). I don't know if that's what's causing the problem but it could be and it wouldn't hurt to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code is really odd, if i had my way i would rewrite most of it, anyways, putting that aside. Currently you have your function within a while loop, why you're looping in the first place is bizarre, you can just do a direct check in the database for the user that you are looking for. See below.

```
include("../connection.php");

function valid_details($username, $password){
    $sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users";
    $sql .= "WHERE user='".$username."' AND pass='".$password."'"; 
    $back = "There is an error. <a href=\"login.php\">Back</a>";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($back);

    return count( $result ) > 0             
}
```

Comment: Well I'll keep in mind your way of coding since I'm not a professional and I don't even go to school for this. Just messing around with a hobby. Thanks anyway. I'll try your answer later on. PS yeah I tried selecting the user I was looking for but using a snippet like this:  $sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user = $user && pass = $ pass"; really bizarre I know.